# How to copy code from Visual Studio to MS Word with EVERY highlight exactly as it is?

Tags: c#, ms-word, formatting, format

I am making a report about my program and I need copy all the code to an MS document. The problem is that I need to keep every colour as it is. I've tried using Notepad++ for this and online converters but it didn't seem to work as some colours got lost. For example if I have something like this:

```
public void SomeFunc(String someArg){}
```

The type "String" seems to lose its colour (the language is C# btw). I also don't want static images in the document (like screenshots of the code or when using the "Insert object" method in MS Word). Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can print to pdf both from notepad++ or directly from VS. If need be you can use a pdf editor to remove unwanted fromatting like headers etc.. You can convert the pdf to docx etc as well..

Comment: When I use copy&paste from VS to MS Word, it includes formating as well. Does that not work?

Comment: @siggi_pop yes it does but as I said I need to keep all the colours the same and some elements like class names as function arguments seem to lose them :/

Comment: Well it ought to be `string` not `String`. Then its color is shown correctly both in VS and in Word.

Comment: Ok i see what you mean. Some font colours are not copied correctly over.

Comment: @TaW yes that is correct but I have some classes of my own which use the colour for class names.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So I was looking for an answer to this and this is what i found.
Go to Extensions (manager) -> look for: Productivity Power Tools -> install & restart VS.
Now when i copy/paste from VS to Word, literally all syntax colors are being copied over 1:1. even the background color is matched.

I use VS 2019 preview these days.

Comment: THANK YOU. Thank you! I love you! Thank you!

Comment: Works well in VS 2022 as well with the 2022 version of the Extension.

Answer (score 9):

Visual Studio | Tools | Options | Text Editor | Advanced
Check box “ Copy rich text on copy/cut", and
Check box “ Use accurate classification” this keep the color for Classes, enums, etc...
it did work for me.

Answer (score 2):

For those stumbling upon the same problem, the answer from @siggi_pop worked well for me but I had to perform a **Paste Special > Formatted Text (RTF)** into MS Word.

A simple Copy / Paste left the code unformatted .

[image: Paste Special Dialog Box]

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing similar issues in `VS2022` like me, I am facing this issue with `VS2022 Enterprise`, I followed all suggestions like installing Productivity Power Tools, Copy rich text on copy/cut e.t.c and nothing worked. In my case *.XAML code is correctly copied and pasted in Word, however *.cs file for C# code is pasted as black.

The only option for me is to open the `*.cs` file in `Visual Studio 2019` or `Visual Studio Code`, which has no Productivity Power Tools installed, but I can do a proper copy and paste with the colour and syntax highlighting of all files including the *.cs file.

Answer (score -1):

VS2019: It seems like there is a limitation for number of lines you can copy with formatting.
Something like around ~300 lines each time.

Answer (score -2):

1. Search for same file in "file manager"
2. Rright click on the file
3. Choose "open with" option then choose "wordpad"
4. Your cpp file is now open in formatted text
5. Copy it to MS word